# Jboss EAP 7 CDI JTA @Transactional

Tags: java, cdi, jta, java-ee-7, jboss-eap-7

I am struggling to understand how I am supposed to deal with JTA and CDI running on a Jboss EAP 7 instance. I can get a transaction manually by injecting a UserTransaction object coming from the container but when I annotate the method with the @Transactional I get an exception regarding no transaction available.... My question is. Is there any config missing? I read briefly that maybe I should create an interceptor myself in order to make it work, but I haven't found any consistent example...

Comment: I feel like there aren't enough details for this question to get an answer better than full JEE tutorial of how to set up an application with database connection. And that's beyond StackOverflow scope. Can you possibly narrow down your problem? For instance you ask "is there any config missing" without mentioning what config you actually have. Or paste any code that could tell us if you're doing what you say you're doing correctly.

Comment: Did you do anything that would have disabled automatic transactions?

Comment: We need to know where did you put the @Transactional annotation. Please share your code. You do not need any interceptor as '@Transactional' is already an Interceptor Binding.

Comment: Hi guys, appreciate the answers.... I don't know exactly what piece of code I could put here that would make your answers easier. I'm trying to use the @Transaction in a method, the same method that works fine when I open the transaction manually using the injected object. My question is, what should I do in order to get a Transactional annotation to work on a simple application? if there is no special config, apart from running this on a jboss instance. So I have a problem in my app...

Comment: If you post your code, and we see how you have annotated your beans, we could help. The problem is that if you are using pure CDI beans, ```@Transactional``` requires an interceptor implementation, it is not provided out of the box. If you use an ejb bean, then you wont need ```@Transactional``` anyway, at least if you use the container managed transaction

Comment: For some reason when I use the annotation on the class level it works now, but still don'ts work for the method level...

Answer (score 0):

In a default JEE container-managed environment, only enterprise beans (usually `@Stateless` beans are used) are transactional. Once you enter such a bean from outside, the transaction will be opened. With the `@javax.transaction.Transactional` annotation you can control the behavior of the transactions, but this is not necessary in default case.

Example bean:

```
@Stateless
public MyBean {
   public void withinTransaction() {
     System.out.println("i'm running within a transaction");
   }
   @Transactional(TxType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
   public void outsideTransaction() {
     System.out.println("no transaction available...");
   }
}
```

- If you call `MyBean.withinTransaction` from a Servlet (e.g. via REST), a new transaction is created (if not already present).
- If you call `MyBean.outsideTransaction`, no transaction will be created.
- If you call `this.outsideTransaction()` from `withinTransaction`, you will still have the transaction available in `outsideTransaction` (because the interceptors are only bound to the bean boundaries)
- If you call `this.withinTransaction()` from `outsideTransaction` no new transaction is created (because the interceptors are only bound to the bean boundaries)
- If `outsideTransaction` would be part of a second bean `AnotherBean`, which `@Inject`s `MyBean`, and you call `MyBean.withinTransaction`, then a new transaction will be created (if not already present). Because you cross bean boundaries between `AnotherBean.outsideTransaction` and `MyBean.withinTransaction`.